# Does H-supplmented module have D2?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, modules

A module $M$ is called H-supplemented if for every submodule $N$ of $M$ there exists a direct summand $D$ of $M$ such that $M = N + X$ if and only if $M = D + X$ for every submodule $X$ of $M$.
A module $M$ has $D2$ if $A\leq M$ such that $M/A$ is isomorphic to a direct summand of $M$, then $A$ is a
direct summand of $M$.
The question is: Does H-supplemented imply D2?

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ $H$-supplemented but not $D2$?

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I don't see why it's D2. Could you please explain?

Comment: @HajerBagdady The claim is that it's not D2. Take $A = (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z, 2\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z)$. If this was a direct summand the module would be isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/2)^3$.